# Дополнение адресной строки параметрами GET

Tags: php, веб-программирование, get

Нужно узнать как сделать дополнение в адресной строке как на [этом сайте](http://www.maximum.md/ru/catalog-513-televizory-smart-svetodiodnye).

```
> А конкретнее при выборе интервале цены появляется
> ..../?price=16200-36729... далее если в окне с товаром выбираем
> допустим вид отображения,теперь ссылка
> такая..../price=22188-39936&viewmode=list а если еще выбрать
> "сортировать по " уже такая
> .../price=22188-39936&viewmode=list&orderby=11
```

Кто подскажет как реализовать такое дополнение?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: При клике на ссылку которая передает запрос в GET,я ставлю условие если приходят параметры с ссылки который мне нужен читаю их с помощью foreach и делаю переменные для <input  type="hidden" >который находиться в форме(которая является фильтром).при использование фильтра передаю параметры фильтра а так же то что было уже в GET.

Если фильтр уже есть и при нажатий на ссылку (в моем случае ссылка это сортировка по цене) читаю тем же методом GET делаю такую переменную ` $link .= "&";
   $link .= $key .= "=";
   $link .= $value;`
и ставлю в <a href="&price=desc$link" >Сортировка по цене</a>

Comment: Могу позже сделать файл с объяснениями если кому то понадобиться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тоже на днях мучался с подобным вопросом,точного решения не нашел,но подсказали кое что полезное,в принципе в моем случае это пригодилось может и вам пригодится. У меня на страничке есть 2 фильтра,так же хотел дополнять URL в зависимости от активированного фильтра.Скидываю код может вам пригодится.

```
function queryStringBuilder(id) {
        var paramsId = id;

         this.getQueryString = function() {
            var queryString = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < paramsId.length; i++) {
                var elem = $(paramsId[i]);
                if (elem.val().trim())
                queryString.push((elem.attr('id') || elem.attr('name')) + "=" + escape(elem.val()));
            }
            return queryString.join("&");
        }
    }

    var queryBuilder = new queryStringBuilder(['#dep-id', '#month']);

    function showQueryString(value) {
        location.search = value;
    }

    $('#dep-id').change(function() {
        showQueryString(queryBuilder.getQueryString());
    });

    $('#month').change(function() {
        showQueryString(queryBuilder.getQueryString());
    });
```

Comment: Спасибо,хоть JS пока не освоил попробую методом тыка его изучить,а тем времен может будет решение ресурсами PHP

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь **HTML5 History API**

Статья:
https://habrahabr.ru/post/123106/

Пример:

```
history.pushState({foo: 'bar'}, "page 2", "/my/custom/path");
```

Документация:
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.